# Opening a small browser with autohotkey

Tags: browser, size, autohotkey

I want to open a small browser. I open the browser with the code below, but how can I adjust the size.

Run chrome.exe "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNb8hHMKUSL4HigPdg2ht4A" " --new-window "

Answer (score 0):

Chrome actually has a command-line option that lets you specify the size of the window. To start a chrome window with a specific size from AHK use the following.

```
Run, chrome.exe --window-size=800`,600 --app=https://example.com
```

Make sure to include the `` ` `` as it escapes the `,`.